# Entity Framework C# query data dynamically

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

1. I have a datatable that has changable - dynamic columns. These columns will be got from another table - another model,
2. The dynamic column name and type can change according to how the user wants to see the datatable, and these dynamically added columns should able to be filtered or ordered. I think I can query and connect these tables with GroupJoin.

Problem: In entity framework, I have to get the data with a model, but model in this case should be changed at runtime, Is this possible? How would I go about implementing this? I have javascript background, and in js objects and its field can be dynamically created or changed, Is there a way to do it in C#? I need a runtime-created list of object that can be filtered and ordered by linq.

Solution? Is there a way to pass data from GroupJoin to a Dictionary<string,string>, where Key is column name, and value is value corresponding to the row, where this dictionary can be filtered and ordered by entity framework linq? Would this work?

Comment: You don't have to use EF for all data access just because you are using it in your project. ORMs are good at state and entity mapping. If you are not doing those things you can use ADO.NET

Comment: Use Dapper for querying dynamic data.